# Login always returns invalid password using flask, sql alchemy, and python

Tags: python, sql, flask

I've been following a Python web tutorial (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dam0GPOAvVI) that has a login/logout/signup feature. I'm able to have new accounts sign up, but when they try to log in, I receive my error message that there is an incorrect password.

Here's where I create the login:

```
@auth.route('/Login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        password = request.form.get('password')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            if check_password_hash(user.password, password):
                flash('Logged in successfully!', category='success')
                login_user(user, remember=True)
                return redirect(url_for('views.home'))
            else:
                flash('Incorrect password, try again.', category='error')
        else:
            flash('Email does not exist.', category='error')

    return render_template("login.html", user=current_user)
```

Along with my database file:

```html
class User(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    email = db.Column(db.String(150), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(150))
    firstName = db.Column(db.String(150))
    JournalEntry = db.relationship('JournalEntry')
    Task = db.relationship('Task')
```

If needed, here's my init file:

```html
db = SQLAlchemy()
DB_NAME = "database.db"


def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'Hi Mr Sea'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = f'sqlite:///{DB_NAME}'
    db.init_app(app)

    from .views import views
    from .auth import auth
    from .TaskList_App import TaskList

    app.register_blueprint(views, url_prefix='/')
    app.register_blueprint(auth, url_prefix='/')

    from .databases import User, JournalEntry, Task

    create_db(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(id):
        return User.query.get(int(id))

    return app


def create_db(app):
    if not path.exists('website/' + DB_NAME):
        db.create_all(app=app)
        print('Created DB!')
```

The error message I receive [tells me that the password is incorrect even though I know I created an account and have entered the correct password. [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lGuH.png) My guess is that somewhere, the password I enter isn't saved and therefore cannot be used for login, although I've looked through my code and haven't seen anywhere this could happen. I'm very new to Flask, Python, and SQL, so apologies if this is a really easy problem!

EDIT: Here's the sign-up function where the account is created and the password is created for an account.

```
@auth.route('/Sign-up', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def sign_up():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        email = request.form.get('email')
        firstName = request.form.get('firstName')
        password1 = request.form.get('password1')
        password2 = request.form.get('password2')

        user = User.query.filter_by(email=email).first()
        if user:
            flash('Email already exists.', category='error')
        elif len(email) < 4:
            flash('Email must be greater than 3 characters.', category='error')
        elif len(firstName) < 2:
            flash('First name must be greater than 1 character.', category='error')
        elif password1 != password2:
            flash('Passwords don\'t match.', category='error')
        elif len(password1) < 7:
            flash('Password must be at least 7 characters.', category='error')
        else:
            new_user = User(email=email, firstName=firstName, password=generate_password_hash(
                password1, method='sha256'))
            db.session.add(new_user)
            db.session.commit()
            login_user(new_user, remember=True)
            flash('Account created!', category='success')
            return redirect(url_for('views.home'))

    return render_template("Sign-up.html", user=current_user)
```

Comment: I've added where the password is hashed (in the sign-up method). If I put a print(password) in the sign-up method right before the redirect to the home screen and sign up for a new account, the password I put in will be printed out. Maybe somewhere along the line the password isn't being encoded? I'm now , instead of invalid password, receiving an error saying that AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'encode', tracing back to an internal hash line: password = password.encode("utf-8")

Comment: Ah never mind, found it! Turns out that in my Login.html, I had set a variable to be equal to "password " instead of "password". Thanks!